# Why is there no division by zero compile time warning or run time crash in this code?

Tags: c++

```
class Divide
{
public:
    float divident, divisor;
    Divide():divident(10.0f),divisor(0.0f){}
};

int main()
{
    Divide obj[100];
    int quotient = obj[1].divident/obj[1].divisor;
    return quotient;
}
```

Edit: Compiler Qt 5.3.1 , Windows 7-32 bit.

Why is there no division by zero warning at compile time or a run time crash happening?

Comment: Why would you expect either?

Comment: I am a tester, I write test cases to crash programs.

Comment: The compiler cannot detect it

Comment: But why do you think this would crash?

Comment: FWIW, I've used compilers that don't produce a compile time error when the division has a literal zero in the divisor.

Comment: Also, your compiler is not Qt. Qt is a library, not a compiler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't crash because you've got a floating-point division by zero, not an integer division by zero. Floating-point division by zero is a valid way to obtain infinity.

The conversion from `float` to `int` is undefined, since infinity is not in `int`'s range, so crashing would be allowed there, but that is simply not what typical implementations make it do.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite a code analysis you would be expecting on the part of the compiler in this particular case. I can't think of an existing compiler that would give you that level of analysis. I don't have much more of an answer than that.